# Bulk import of excel data into sql and GUID issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, guid

There is an application that users use to capture data. For each record a uniqueidentifier is created and added to a row(GUID).

There is a requirement to bulk upload by passing the application. Data is stored in excel. I am using the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 to select the data from Excel and doing C# SqlBulkCopy tyo insert the values.

Issue is setting the rowduid column to a new GUID for each record. How can i achieve this. I thought by doing something like a "Select *, newguid as ID FROM [sheet1$]" but i dont know if there is such a query in excel. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You can use Microsoft Query for this

Comment: Can't you just set the column to have a default value of `NEWID()`? "ALTER TABLE [yourTable] ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Whatever DEFAULT newid() FOR [theColumn]"

Comment: @Corak Requirement is to not alter table. I know i know.

Comment: If you're working with [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx), do you have an intermediate [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) you can alter? Because there you can also set a [DataColumn.DefaultValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.datacolumn.defaultvalue.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

(Since a default value of NEWID() can't be created) Can you do a post-insert UPDATE, such as ...

```
CREATE TABLE ##GUID(
    ID INT,
    ValueOne VARCHAR(1),
    NewGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)

INSERT INTO ##GUID (ID,ValueOne)
VALUES (1,'A')
    , (2,'B')
    , (3,'C')

SELECT *
FROM ##GUID

-- after the INSERT, update the table with the GUID
UPDATE ##GUID
SET NewGuid = NEWID()

SELECT *
FROM ##GUID

DROP TABLE ##GUID
```